# Merging two univariate functions gracefully

Tags: interpolation

Suppose I tell you that 
$$ f(0) = 0 $$
$$ f'(0) = 0 $$
and 
$$
   f''(0) = a
$$
for known $a>0$, whereas for large $x$
$$
    f'(x) \approx \cosh^{-1}(x) 
$$
for $x>2$. Knowing nothing else about $f(x)$, what is a sensible interpolation consistent with this information?